# Perl database connection

Tags: perl, dbi

I am new in perl, and I need to connect the database use DBI. My code as follows:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
use Getopt::Long;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);
use IO::File;
use warnings;

 $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:);


  if (!$dbh) {
    &logMsg(0, "$DBI::errstr");
    die;
  } else {&logMsg(0,"Connection to $dbName DB OK")}
```

I already set the values. Its kind like connection failed, but I didn't get any errors. I also check the log file, there is nothing showing. What can I do for checking the errors? Thanks for any comments and help.

Comment: Turn on [tracing](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING). Also, enable [`RaiseError`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) so you don't have to manually check for errors after every call. And always `use strict;`!

Comment: Hi @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I used  strict to check, there is still no error showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything wrong with your code, unless `logMsg` just doesn't work, but it's a tedious way to go about using DBI.

Rather than checking if something went wrong with DBI, it's much better to set DBI to throw an error. You can do this with [RaiseError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError).

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
              "dbi:ODBC:DSN=$dbName;Server=$dbHost",
              $dbUser, $dbPassword,
              { RaiseError => 1 }
          );
```

Now if DBI has a failure, including trying to connect, it will throw an error and stop the program. This avoids having to check for an error every time you use the database (you'll forget).

Comment: Hi I run these code in Linux, and I tried your code and add the RaiseError. There is nothing change and showing.

Comment: @Kyan Maybe `logMsg` doesn't work? Try a deliberately wrong password to make an error happen. Also check you're running the code you think you are.

Comment: I think logMsg is working, because I use it on other place, and it print the error and message.

Comment: @Kyan You use it with a 0? Is the log level set properly? Why assume? Try a print or something. Or try to put something into the database.

Comment: yes, I try to put something into the database, but first I need to connect to the database. I wrote and printed a word out before the code $dbh, but another word which I use to print after the code $dbh is not working.

Comment: 'print "Hello";'

   ' # Establish database connection'
    '$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:DSN=$dbName;Server=$dbHost",
                         $dbUser,
                         $dbPassword);'

'print "World";'

Comment: @Kyan Is the connection hanging? Turn on tracing like I suggested in my comment on your question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Hi, I check the tracing stuff, but I still have no idea how to turn on it.

Comment: @Kyan Add `DBI->trace('4|CON');` before your call to `connect` and edit the output into your question.

Comment: @Kyan I get the feeling you're trying to run this code via a remote web server or something. Any errors should be in the server's error log. Are you checking that? Also it would be much easier to debug this problem by running the program on the command line.

Comment: @Schwern Hi, thanks for your help, I checked the log file, the problem is no error in the log file.

Comment: Is that possible I miss the DBI::ODBC? I already installed DBI. Should I install the ODBC stuff?

Comment: @Kyan Yes, you need a database driver, [DBD::ODBC](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC). But more importantly you need to find out where your errors are going. Try a program that's just `die` and find the error.

Comment: @Schwern thank you very much, I am doing the ODBC driver first. If I get the result, I will post the answer.

Comment: @Schwern Hi, I tried to install the ODBC and I used the comment:  apt-get install odbcinst     After I installed, I check the ODBC if it installed properly, and I got the error: odbcinst: SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with. I searched online but didn't find the answer. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @Kyan Nope, sorry. You should ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DBI;
 $dbh = DBI->connect('Your_Database_Name', 'user_id','Password');
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare ("select * from Table_name");
 $sth->execute();
 my @row_ary = $sth->hetshrow_array;
 foreach $item (@row_ary)
 {
 print "$item\n";
 }
```